# Why are my flex-items turning up way outside the container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using flex-boxes to show small texts of varying length.

However, when wrapping them in `flex-direction: column;` they turn up way outside the screen. I want them to be wrapped inside the container, so that the are visible on one page.

Why do they turn up way to the right(you'll have to scroll right in the [codepen](https://codepen.io/Ginner/pen/VqpavR) window to see 'Test service 5', '6' and '7'), and what would be a solution?

```css
.content {
  background-color: #ffa676;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.content-heading {
  width: 100%;
}

.content-main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  max-height: 750px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #c5dda9;
}

.content-main>div {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #f2c888;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="content-heading">
    <p class="pagetitle-pretext">My</p>
    <h1 class="pagetitle">Services</h1>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div class="content-main">
    <div>
      <h2>Test Service 1</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id sea rebumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id choro ridens, mea populo integre adipiscing ei, no habeo aeque soleat cum. Nominati argumentum </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>Test Service 2</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id sea rebumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id choro ridens, mea populo integre adipiscing ei, no habeo aeque soleat cum. Nominati argumentum an his, pro ex doming lucilius honestatis, nec id pertinax vituperatoribus. Ad
        eripuit concludaturque eum. Ne eirm</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>Test Service 3</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id sea rebumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id choro ridens, mea populo integre adipiscing ei, no habeo aeque soleat cum. Nominati argumentum an his, pro ex doming lucilius honestatis, nec id pertinax vituperatoribus. Ad
        eripuit concludaturque eum. Ne eirm</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>Test Service 4</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id sea rebumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id choro ridens, mea populo integre adipiscing ei, no habeo aeque soleat cum. Nominati argumentum an his, pro ex doming lucilius honestatis, nec id pertinpopulo integre adipiscing
        ei, no habeo aeque soleat cum. Nominati argumentum an his, pro ex doming lucilius honestatis, nec id pertinpopu lo integre adipiscing ei, no habeo aeque soleat cum. Nominati argumentum an his, pro ex doming lucilius honestatis, nec id pertinax
        vituperatoribus. Ad eripuit concludaturque eum. Ne eirm</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>Test Service 5</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id sea rebumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id choro ridens, mea populan his, pro ex doming lucilius honestatis, nec id pertinax vituperatoribus. Ad eripuit concludaturque eum. Ne eirmo integre adipiscing ei, no habeo aeque
        soleat cum. Nominati argumentum an his, pro ex doming lucilius honestatis, nec id pertinax vituperatoribus. Ad eripuit concludaturque eum. Ne eirm</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>Test Service 6</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id sea rebumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id choro ridens, mea populo integre adipiscing ei, no habeo aeque soleat olor sit amet, id choro ridens, mea populo integre adipiscing ei, no habeo aeque soleat cucum. Nominati
        argumentum an his, pro ex doming lucilius honestatis, nec id pertinax vituperatoribus. Ad eripuit concludaturque eum. Ne eirm</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>Test Service 7</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id sea rebumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id choro ridens, mea populo integre adipiscing ei, no habeo aeque soleat cum. Nominati argumentum an his, pro ex doming lucilius onestatis, nec id pertinax vituperatoribus. Ad eripuit
        concludaturque eum. Ne eirm</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/Ginner/pen/VqpavR)

Comment: the problem seems to be that you are using `max-width` on the "article" divs. that causes the divs to be to high to fit inside your `max-height` container and a second column is created. what kind of layout are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. I'm trying to achieve a layout where the texts are next to each other, but of varying length without stretching the one next to it, hence i cannot use a grid, as a long text would cause a small text next to it, to use excessive space.
Which divs are you referring to as "article divs"?

Comment: Wow! You're right! Just changing `max-width: 50%;` to `width:50%;` solves it. Thank you so much, I'd be embarrassed to say how much time I've spent on this. Again, thank you!

Comment: glad i could help. "article divs" for me are always divs that are like news teaser on a page, classic blog style ... image(optional), headline, text, link(optional). just how I think of a webpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood your problem correctly, the issue is with

```
.content-main > div {
   max-width: 50%;
}
```

If you change it to just `width: 50%` it fixes your problem.

Note: Using this method, each element will always be 50% of the width (even if there aren't enough elements to wrap) so it may not be a perfect solution for you.

Comment: Yeah, that does it! Thank you. No, its perfect, I'll try and figure it out from here. Again, thank you.